# Javascript simple script for changing input value by <a> name element

Tags: javascript, html

I need this script to work real badly. been trying to fix it all day.
Basicly, whenever you click on an example from the list it needs to update either the Normal background, or the Hovered background (as user select).
but it requires IDs so i can add links as new examples, so whenever i add a new  with a value in it's 'name' it needs to be a new example.

its like having the same script , but twice. one for normal bg, and one for hovered.

theres also a list show/hide script that i haven't figured out how to make work,
i'm not much of a javascript scripter but i managed to get that in a few hours.

i really need some help here, and i will appreciate if you help me.
thank you.
/Edward

jsfiddle.net/5tq2Y this is the fiddle. but it won't work on it for some reason

the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change_bg(){
    document.getElementById('button_bg').value = 'BY THE DIFFRERENT <A> NAMES';
}
function change_bg_hover(){
    document.getElementById('button_bg_hover').value = 'BY THE DIFFRERENT <A> NAMES';
}
</script>
```

the input that needs the updates:

```
<input type="text" id="button_bg" name="button_bg" value="">
<input type="text" id="button_bg_hover" name="button_bg" value="">
```

the html:

```
<b>Show/Hide Background examples list</b><br />
<a id="changer" name="images/examples/1.jpg" onclick="change_bg()"><u>Example 1 Red</u></a><br />
<a id="changer" name="images/examples/2.jpg" onclick="change_bg()"><u>Example 2 Blue</u></a><br />

<b>Show/Hide HOVERED Background examples list</b><br />
<a id="changer" name="images/examples/1_hovered.jpg" onclick="change_bg_hover()"><u>Example 1 Blue Hover</u></a><br />
<a id="changer" name="images/examples/2_hovered.jpg" onclick="change_bg_hover()"><u>Example 2 Red Hover</u></a><br />
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? could you clarify

Comment: Also a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would help.

Comment: thank you for the fast reply.
yes, what i'm trying to do is having a list of images links as examples, and whenever the user wants to auto-fill in that example (once clicked on) it will auto type it in the input.
there are 2 background images for the menu, one for normal link, and one for hovered. the user has to choose between the examples (or fill in with his own link).

so, lets say that i want to make my list of examples, such as adding normal backgrounds or hovered backgrounds, ill just add an <a> link to the source file with the image url in the name="".

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5tq2Y/ this is the fiddle. but it won't work on it for some reason.

Comment: Just fyi, don't include the script tags in the fiddle. It will include them for you as appropriate. I've also seen it cause the fiddle to choke on some browsers, but that was a while ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you [can't have multiple elements with the same `id` value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2), so your `id="changer"` will have to change. I would propose `class="changer"`.

**Edit:** I actually gave them unique ID's so you could look them up for the complicated means of retrieving their attributes in the fixed code. If you want them to share a common rule for css or javascript targeting, I still recommend `class="changer"`.

I think what you want to have is this:

1. User clicks a link.
2. Background of a different element changes
3. What it changes to depends on what was in the `name` attribute of the clicked link.

If that's accurate, well, I don't even know how to do it cleanly without jquery. Try this for the html:

```
<a href="#" id="changer1" name="images/examples/1.jpg" onclick="change_bg(document.getElementById('changer1'))"><u>Example 1 Red</u></a><br />
<a href="#" id="changer2" name="images/examples/2.jpg" onclick="change_bg(document.getElementById('changer2'))"><u>Example 2 Blue</u></a><br />
```

and this for the javascript

```
function change_bg(elem){
    document.getElementById('button_bg').value = elem.name;
}
function change_bg_hover(elem){
    document.getElementById('button_bg').value = elem.name;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aGCNn/

Ask how to do it with jQuery, you'll like the answer. I promise!

Comment: i'm going to test this out.
can you please check the hide/show divs?

Comment: What divs? I reread your question, comments and checked the fiddle, but I don't see any divs mentioned anywhere.

Comment: <b>Show/Hide List</b> ones needs to be hidden divs as far as I've read on google. then, able to show  or hide the whole list of examples once clicked on the Show or Hide <a>

Comment: Ah, that's easy. Updated the fiddle (changes to css, js and html, be sure to get them all): http://jsfiddle.net/aGCNn/1/

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle that work http://jsfiddle.net/juzVG/2/
Please check if this what you want.

I also made a few modifications to the code.

```
<a href="#" id="changer" name="images/examples/1.jpg" onclick="change_bg();return false;">Example 1 Red</a><br />
<a href="#" id="changer" name="images/examples/2.jpg" onclick="change_bg();return false;">Example 2 Blue</a><br />

<b>Show/Hide HOVERED Background examples list</b><br />
<a href="#" id="changer" name="images/examples/1_hovered.jpg" onclick="change_bg_hover();return false;">Example 1 Blue Hover</a><br />
<a href="#" id="changer" name="images/examples/2_hovered.jpg" onclick="change_bg_hover();return false;">Example 2 Red Hover</a><br />
```

Comment: hmm, it's a progres. thank you sir, but the problem is that i need the value to change as you click on the link.